# View comments in admin area before approval

Tags: 6, comments, theming

How can I view posted comments in admin area before approval?

I mean previewing comment INSIDE admin area not node's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default comment administration page does not show you the entire comment. But it shows author and some other helpful information that should be helpful for most users to decide anther delete it or not.

You can replicate this form using Views and Views Bulk Operations module.

Just install both modules and create a new View on comment entity. 
You can add a new page with a path like admin/content/comment2 (so you are not overriding the default page - if you want to do so, enter same path as core comment admin page).

Add necessary fields and set style as table. You can add a VBO checkbox and actions by adding a checkbox field.

There is an action "delete comment" that you can use to delete comments via VBO. 
hooks will work without a problem.